# Is there an R function to select n individuals based on group?

Tags: r

I have a data set of 12.5 million records and I need to randomly select about 2.5 million. However, these individuals are in 55284 groups and I want to keep groups intact.

So basically I want to remove groups until I've got 2.5 million records left OR select groups until I have about 2.5 million individuals.

If this is my data:

```
data <- data.frame(
    id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    group = (1, 1, 2, 2, 3)
)
```

I wouldn't want to remove id1 and keep id2, I'd like to either keep them both or discard both, because they are in the same group(2).
So ideally, this function randomly selects a group, counts these individuals and puts them in a data set, then does the same thing again, keeps counting the individuals until it has about 2.5 million (it is okay to say: if n exceeds 2.5 stop putting groups into new data set).

I haven't been able to find a function and I am not yet skilled enough to put something together myself, unfortunately.
Hope someone can help me out!

Thanks

Comment: Stratified sampling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment hence answering. Do you need something like this ?

```
#Order data by group so rows with same groups are together 
data1 <- data[order(data$group), ]
#Get all the groups in first 2.5M entries
selected_group <- unique(data1$group[1:2500000])

#Subset those groups so you have all groups intact
final_data <- data1[data1$group %in% selected_group, ]
```

---

For a random approach, we can use `while` loop

```
#Get all the groups in the data
all_groups <- unique(data$group)
#Variable to hold row indices
rows_to_sample <- integer()

#While the number of rows to subset is less than 2.5M
while (length(rows_to_sample) <= 2500000) {
   #Select one random group
   select_group <- sample(all_groups, 1)
   #Get rows indices of that group
   rows_to_sample <- c(rows_to_sample, which(data$group == select_group))
   #Remove that group from the all_groups
   all_groups <- setdiff(all_groups, select_group)
}

data[rows_to_sample, ]
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that would work, however, this wouldn't really randomly selects groups as you're just picking the first ones.

Answer (score 1):

here is a possibility. I demonstrate it using toydata and threshold of 33 (instead of 2.5) million. First I create the toy group vector:

```
threshold <- 33
set.seed(111)
mygroups <- rep(1:10, rpois(10, 10))
```

In this toy example group 1 has 10 individuals, group 2 has 8 individuals and so on.
Now I put the groups in random order and use `cumsum` to determine when the threshold is exceeded:

```
x <- cumsum(table(mygroups)[sample(1:10)])
randomgroups <- as.integer(names(x[x <= threshold]))
randomgroups
[1] 1 7 5
```